# How to group a graph according to its trend?

Tags: excel

I have created a trendline of 8 wind stations in Malaysia. The data comprises 30 years of maximum wind speed data per month. I have used a 95% confidence interval to get the mean of each wind station. I have plotted the graph of the mean wind speed for all wind station as below. The issue is I cannot cluster or group the graph using a normal K-means approach.

[image: Mean wind speed]

The question is, how can I cluster or group the graph according to its trend? For example, Alor Setar, Bayan Lepas, and, Butterworth are in one group because of its trend.

Comment: Can you explain what that grouping would look like in the chart? Excel plots data from the worksheet. For most chart scenarios you will need to change the worksheet data layout to affect the chart appearance. But it is not clear what you want to achieve. Please edit your question and explain. Edit the question. Then post a comment.

Comment: After searching, the exact name of the method is actually time series clustering, the current data as below. It can be done in Python, which I'm not used to...